# "None" return using 2 classes with inheritance in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm using 2 classes with inheritance in Python(3.x).

The x variable below receive a "None" return although I was expected something.

The code is :

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        print("Init Parent")


    def getSomeValue(self):
        print("getSomeValue Parent")
        x = self.returnConstant() # "None", which what is not what I expected !!!
        print(x)


    def returnConstant(self):
        print("returnConstant Parent")
        return 'A'



class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Init Child")


    def getSomeValue(self):
        print("getSomeValue Child")
        Parent.getSomeValue(self)


    def returnConstant(self):
        print("returnConstant Child")
        Parent.returnConstant(self)



def main():
    c = Child()
    c.getSomeValue()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is :

```
Init Child
getSomeValue Child
getSomeValue Parent
returnConstant Child
returnConstant Parent
None
```

It may be obvious but I am unfamiliar with OOP and Python. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: `returnConstant` in the child class does not return anything.

Comment: In fact, I do not want to redefine the function returnConstant in the child class, I just want to use the Parent definition, which return something.

What would be the right way to write the function returnConstant in the child class ?

Comment: Either don’t redefine `returnConstant` in the child and then the parent’s method will be called, or use `super` See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super

Comment: @user5012562 you don't need to do anything to reuse a method from the parent class.